# Filtering some data from Spark dataframe based on CSV records

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a `CSV` file containing some words. Total no. of words in csv file won't exceed 50k records.

I have a `Spark Dataframe` created from a `JSON` file having `keywords` column. What I need to do is filter out the records from dataframe whose `keywords` column value matches with the value present in CSV file. Here, Matches means if the word in csv file appears in dataframe column.

Taking an example, let's say there is a word `"baby toys"` in csv file and `spark dataframe` looks like this

```
***Keywords***
new baby toys
baby toys for all
costly baby toys price
baby has toys
```

In the above first 3 rows should be filtered out as all having the word `baby toys` in sequence.

To implement, I am doing something like this.

```
1. Reading csv file and creating a dataframe.

2. Collecting all the words as an array of strings from dataframe created above as
val negativeKeywords = csvDF.distinct.map(x => x.getString(0)).collect()

3. Creating a UDF to match the words - one from negative list created above and other from Spark dataframe(created in step 4)
 val udfmatch= udf((x: String) => {
      val loop = new Breaks
      var check = false
      loop.breakable{
        for(s <- negativeKeywords){
          if(x.contains(s)){
            check = true
            loop.break
          }
        }
      }
      check
  })

4. Created spark dataframe from JSON file. 
5. Filter from the above JSON dataframe using UDF defined above. 
   sparkDf.filter(udfmatch(col("keyword_text")))
```

In the above, I am iterating over the entire `csv` words list(until I find it) for every keyword present in `Spark dataframe`, which i think is not right and time consuming.
Can someone please suggest a better way.

Comment: Is `x.contains(s)` a requirement or is it ok to match tokens? For example should "BigToysTools" match "Toys" or is it ok to tokenize to "big", "toys", "tools" and then match the full tokens?

Comment: @ollik1 We can't tokenize as words need to be matched in exact sequence

Comment: could you have not done using this native isin on the json Df? approach I  can think of is reading your csv into Seq[String] and map over it Df using when  function with .isin.. would that not work for your situation?

Comment: @user2315840 Can you please give us a  bit of code snippet to make it more understandable.

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with a Seq of keywords that are coming from csv; we can use fold left and use contains like below code:

```
val conds= seq(("new toys")).toList
val result = conds.foldLeft(yourJsonDf){(newdf,conds)=>
 newdf.filter(!col("yourJsonColumnToFitlerOn").contains(conds))}
```

This will get you the rows that do not match  your list.  if you want to have those filtered rows only.  you can simply join on your "yourJsonColumntoFilteron" back to your original DF and use leftanti join 
something like below code

```
val filteredResults = originalDf.join(result ,Seq("yourJsonColumnToFilterOn"),"leftanti")
filteredResults.show()
```

Per you question of returning null DF is due to the nature of spark processing of foldLeft.  it does not break the loop over the iteration of items in your list. or Simply put foldleft does not get executed N times based on elements in your List. the execution is only 1 time which saves you a lot of time and resources and does not have to worry on GC cleanup.   hope the above changes in the Answer meets your request. 
Cheers,

Comment: Thanks .. I will check it.. just one thing in the comment you mentioned isin but here you suggested contains.. which one to use?

Comment: Also, above one is working perfectly fine. But one strange is if I remove "!" in filter, then I am getting empty dataframe.. I though it would have been opposite. Could you please help here

Comment: newdf.filter(col("yourJsonColumnToFitlerOn").contains(conds)) is not working

Comment: what is not working?  can you elaborate? also If i understood your question correctly you need to remove those rows that match words in your csv? is that correct assumption ?

Comment: contains will do wild card search where isin a string match .. if i read your question correctly you should be using contains as it will ignore the  words before and after  as long as it has the words or list of words in the same order. it will pick them.